# Cant change table colum

Tags: db2

Iam just trying to rename the column in my table.

Column name: AGGREGATE_ID
Data type name: CHARACTER
Length: 15

```
 ALTER TABLE 'headers' CHANGE 'aggregate_id' 'ENGINE' char(15)
```

I always get the error masssage

"ALTER TABLE 'headers' CHANGE 'aggregate_id' 'ENGINE'char(15)
DB21034E  The command was processed as an SQL statement because it was not a
valid Command Line Processor command.  During SQL processing it returned:
SQL0104N  An unexpected token "ALTER TABLE 'headers' CHANGE 'agg" was found
following "BEGIN-OF-STATEMENT".  Expected tokens may include:
"<create_variable>".  SQLSTATE=42601"

I dont know what to do anymore :(

Comment: FOR mysql - That looks like single quotes around the column names (and copies as such) change to backticks voting to close as typo. What DB are you actually using?

Comment: Why is your question marked with mysql and db2? Specify the correct database system and add the OS!

Comment: Based on the error message it is Db2 and you ran into a syntax error

Comment: I have removed the [tag:mysql] tag.

Answer (score 1):

In Db2, [renaming a column as ALTER TABLE](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0000888.html) is done like this:

```
ALTER TABLE "headers" RENAME COLUMN "aggregate_id" TO ENGINE
```

If you use double quotes around an identifier, it is stored as provided. If you don't use the quotes, the string is converted to uppercase. Hence I did not use quotes for ENGINE.

Comment: Really? With single-quotes around the identifiers? I am not a DB2 user, but single-quotes are normally for string literals, not identifiers.

Comment: Lack of coffee :). It should be double quotes. I copied it over from the question.